# How to add access key to button in Inno Setup

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, inno-setup

I want to add *Alt* functions to my audio button;
<kbd>Alt+M</kbd> for **Mute** and <kbd>Alt+P</kbd> for **Play**
Like this

[image: screenshot]

How? What code should be entered? Where will I insert the code? Here's my script:

```pascal
SoundCtrlButton := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
SoundCtrlButton.Parent := WizardForm;
SoundCtrlButton.Left := 8;
SoundCtrlButton.Top := WizardForm.ClientHeight - 
  SoundCtrlButton.Height - 8;
SoundCtrlButton.Width := 40;
SoundCtrlButton.Caption :=
  ExpandConstant('{cm:SoundCtrlButtonCaptionSoundOff}');
SoundCtrlButton.OnClick := @SoundCtrlButtonClick;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows controls, you just prefix a letter in control caption with `&` to mark is as an access key.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/defining-mnemonics-access-keys#mnemonics-access-keys

```pascal
SoundCtrlButton.Caption := '&Mute';
```

Or in your case, indirectly via a custom message:

```
[CustomMessages]
SoundCtrlButtonCaptionSoundOff=&Mute
```

[image: keyboard accelertor]

---

See how the standard button captions are defined in `Default.isl`:

```
ButtonBack=< &Back
ButtonNext=&Next >
ButtonInstall=&Install
```