# Why do we use '&' character in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Here's a page from documentation: [`CreateInputQueryPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_createinputquerypage.htm).

Why do we use `&` character in the following part?

```pascal
Page.Add('&Name:', False);
Page.Add('&Company:', False);
```

I tried omitting it but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It determines, what letter serves as an [access key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/defining-mnemonics-access-keys#mnemonics-access-keys) for the control (for controls that have labels on their own, like checkboxes, radio buttons or buttons) or for the control associated with a label using the `TLabel.FocusControl` property (for controls without their own labels, like edit boxes, combo boxes, list boxes, etc).

So in this case, if you press <kbd>Alt+N</kbd>, the focus moves to the *"Name"* box.  While if you press <kbd>Alt+C</kbd>, the focus moves to the *"Company"* box.

[image]

Note that on the modern versions of Windows, the underline appears only once Windows determines, that you want to use the keyboard for navigating around the window. So for example after you press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

---

If you want to change an access key of built-in Inno Setup controls, change their cation using the [`[Messages]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=messagessection) or in `.isl` files.

```
[Messages]
ButtonBack=< Bac&k
```

[image]

---

A related question: [How to add access key to button in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40489885/850848)