# How to disable the navigation keys on Inno Setup installer GUI?

Tags: windows, inno-setup

Is there a way to completely disable the navigation hotkeys on the installers created by Inno Setup?

Currently pressing <kbd>B</kbd> is like like clicking on the <kbd>BACK</kbd> button, and pressing <kbd>N</kbd> will get you to the <kbd>NEXT</kbd> page. I would like to disable this behaviour, so the installer is not reacting to these keys, and maybe other navigation keys which are there.

I'm adding a component search ability on the components page. These hotkeys were breaking it. As if someone is searching for a name that is containing either *N* or *B*, it was switching the page, totally ruining the functionality I added there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First this is a bad idea. The keyboard accelerators are useful and they are absolutely needed for example by blind users.*

*If the accelerators break your search functionality, then you have implemented it incorrectly. Have you noticed that if you type the hotkeys on input boxes, the keys correctly type into the box and don't trigger the buttons? You seem to have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218578).*

---

Anyway...

The keyboard accelerators are controlled by adding the `&` symbol in control caption before the letter, that should work as the accelerator. In the GUI the letter is then underlined (after you click the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key).

For example, this is how the buttons are defined in the `Default.isl`:

```
ButtonBack=< &Back
ButtonNext=&Next >
ButtonInstall=&Install
```

Just remove the `&`, if you do not want them. Either modify the `Default.isl` or override the caption in the [`[Messages]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=messagessection) in your `.iss`.

---

Related questions:

- [How to add access key to button in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40489885/850848)
- [Why do we use '&' character in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64677060/850848)